# Copied dropdown menu doesn't work on one page mobile/tablet devices

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build a website. I've built a dropdown menu for mobile and tablet devices and I have the following problem. The drop-down menu works on every site except "Referenzen". But the code is copied, so it's the exactly same on each site.

Here's my code. You can try it on http://jenquisi.bplaced.net/

It works perfectly on PC. I'd be glad if you could help me!

```
<div class="dropdown visible-xs">
    <img class="dropdown_img" src="img/dropdown.png" alt="dropdown_icon" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Über uns</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html">Leistungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="reference-alt.html">Referenzen</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-map.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Neuigkeiten</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using two versions of jquery. Remove the last one (1.10).

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Viel spaß beim coden. ;)